# Listen to all responses from a Vec of WebSocketStream(s) in tokio select

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have multiple streams of type `WebSocketStream<MaybeTlsStream<TcpStream>>` bundled together in a `Vec`. I want to `.send()` a message to a single stream (chosen at random) and listen for responses from all the streams.

I can loop over the vector, pick one at random to `.send()` the message but how can I listen for responses from all of the streams? The issue is in `Some(_) = ws.streams.next() => {}`.

```
use tokio; // 1.35.1
use tokio_tungstenite::{MaybeTlsStream, WebSocketStream};
use tokio::TcpStream;

struct WS {
    streams: Vec<WebSocketStream<MaybeTlsStream<TcpStream>>>,
};

impl WS {
    async fn connect(...) -> Self {
        ...
        Self {
            streams
        }
    }
}

async fn send_msg(ws: &mut WS, msg: String) {
    let random_stream = ws.streams.iter_mut().choose_multiple(&mut rand::thread_rng(), 1)[0];
    random_stream.send(..).await.unwrap();
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (tx, mut rx) = tokio::sync::mpsc::unbounded_channel();
    let mut ws = WS::connect(..);
    
    loop {
        tokio::select! {
            Some(msg) = rx.recv() => {
                send_msg(ws, msg.to_string()).await;
            }
            // Cannot call .next() here as we need a future
            Some(_) = ws.streams.next() => {
                // How do we receive all messages from all streams here?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `WebSocketStream<MaybeTlsStream<TcpStream>>` implement `futures::stream::Stream` you can use [`futures::stream::select_all::SelectAll`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/select_all/struct.SelectAll.html) instead of `Vec` to hold your streams. Then you can use it in place of all the streams in `tokio::select!`, you can access the individual streams with [`iter_mut()`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/select_all/struct.SelectAll.html#method.iter_mut) just like you do with the `Vec`.